# How do I use g_settings_schema_get_key from python?

Tags: python, glib, pygobject, gio, gsettings

I'm following http://www.micahcarrick.com/gsettings-python-gnome-3.html to use GSettings from python, and I've succeeded to read a value:

```
from gi.repository import Gio
gso=Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences")
gso.get_value("focus-mode")
```

This returns a "GLib.Variant", one of a set of enum values.  To get valid enums I can set, I use:

```
gso.get_range("focus-mode")
```

However, the docs say

> g_settings_get_range has been deprecated since version 2.40 and should not be used in newly-written code.
>   Use g_settings_schema_key_get_range() instead.

So, how do I use g_settings_schema_key_get_range from python?

More generally, how can I introspect Gio to work out how to use it from python given the C docs?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regular python interpreter inspection:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
>>> help (Gio)
>>> help (Gio.Settings)
>>> help (Gio.SettingsSchema)
```

...etc. It's not always very helpful but at least you can see whether a function exists in a namespace. Based on the docs, I would expect something like this to work:

```
schema = gso.get_property('settings-schema')
if schema.has_key('focus-mode'):
    key = schema.get_key('focus-mode')
    print (key.get_range())
```

Comment: Indeed, the output is `('enum', <['click', 'sloppy', 'mouse']>)`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [online documentation for PyGobject](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/SettingsSchemaKey.html#Gio.SettingsSchemaKey.get_range):

> This function will return a GLib.Variant that fully describes the
> range of values that are valid for self.
>
> The type of GLib.Variant returned is (sv). The string describes the
> type of range restriction in effect. The type and meaning of the value
> contained in the variant depends on the string.
>
> If the string is 'type' then the variant contains an empty array. The
> element type of that empty array is the expected type of value and all
> values of that type are valid.
>
> If the string is 'enum' then the variant contains an array enumerating
> the possible values. Each item in the array is a possible valid value
> and no other values are valid.
>
> If the string is 'flags' then the variant contains an array. Each item
> in the array is a value that may appear zero or one times in an array
> to be used as the value for this key. For example, if the variant
> contained the array ['x', 'y'] then the valid values for the key would
> be [], ['x'], ['y'], ['x', 'y'] and ['y', 'x'].
>
> Finally, if the string is 'range' then the variant contains a pair of
> like-typed values – the minimum and maximum permissible values for
> this key.
>
> This information should not be used by normal programs. It is
> considered to be a hint for introspection purposes. Normal programs
> should already know what is permitted by their own schema. The format
> may change in any way in the future – but particularly, new forms may
> be added to the possibilities described above.
>
> You should free the returned value with GLib.Variant.unref() when it
> is no longer needed.

That documentation is a gem. By the way, I believe you would also be interested in [`gso.get_enum(key)`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Settings.html#Gio.Settings.get_enum):

> Gets the value that is stored in self for key and converts it to the enum value that it represents.
>
> In order to use this function the type of the value must be a string and it must be marked in the schema file as an enumerated type.
>
> It is a programmer error to give a key that isn’t contained in the schema for self or is not marked as an enumerated type.
>
> If the value stored in the configuration database is not a valid value for the enumerated type then this function will return the
> default value.
>
> New in version 2.26.